# How to setup my building's networking with shared modem?

Tags: networking, router, modem, switch

In my building we are sharing the internet connection. All of the occupants have an individual router in their unit.

The first challenge is that we are 6 units but we have only a 5 ports router and 5 ports switch available. So that forces us to do something like:
[modem] - [main router] - [switch] where some units' routers are connected to the switch and some others to the main router directly:

```
[modem] - [main router] - [switch]
                 | | |     | | |
                 1 2 3     4 5 6
```

There is quite a bit of debate about how it should be configured. Currently they are trying to have the modem be the DHCP server and turn of any DHCP server everywhere so that we're all on one big network.

I don't like this because of security reason, and my understanding is that we don't need to do that.

IMO the natural way to set this up would be to have several networks:

- [modem] - [main router] : the modem is the DHCP server and assigns an (external) IP to the main router
- [main router]  - [switch] - [unit routers], i.e. this part:

  ```
  [main router] - [switch]
         | | |     | | |
         1 2 3     4 5 6
  ```

The main router is the DHCP server and assigns (external) IPs to the individual routers.

- [unit router] - [unit devices]:

The unit router is the DHCP server and creates its own LAN for the devices connected to it.

I also believe that this should be the way it works out of the box, i.e. if I reset all the devices they should be working like that by default.

Is my understanding correct? Anything I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: How many public IP addresses does your ISP provide for this connection? Is there a requirement to _have_ a "main router"?

Comment: It's a simple internet plan so I'm guessing 1 public IP address which might be dynamic, not sure why that matters though. There is no requirement to have a router, I'd prefer just having a bigger switch but we don't have that atm.

Comment: It matters because your post says "let the main router assign external IP addresses to each router".

Comment: Updated my question to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

Any solution using multiple routers (unless they acting as Access-Point only) will result in Double NAT. Double NAT is not a disaster, but is not optimal and expect will cause an issue for someone eventually, probably with gaming or VOIP applications. Addressing it properly requires a lot of networking knowledge. I can offer two approaches: The first would be to install a new router with capability of having six or more separate LAN networks. Requires a lot of networking knowledge, but if you have the appetite, learn about the open-source firewall pfSense. It can run on PC hardware with a couple PCIe multi-port NICs added to provide 7 physical network interfaces, or (instead of 7 physical ports) using VLANs (even more networking knowledge) and a VLAN capable switch. This really is a large project for anyone without a networking background. Second approach is less technical (but still not simple). If you are familiar with Client Isolation mode used on most public WiFi networks (enforces that each client may get to the Internet, but not see any other clients), it is that feature implemented on a wired network switch. Some managed switches have this feature. All units and their devices would all be served DHCP addresses on the same network, from the main router. The main router LAN interface would connect to the managed switch. Each unit would get a port on the managed switch. Switch ports that connect to units would be set to isolation mode. This would prevent units from seeing each other on the LAN. While you'll have to learn a fair amount about managed switches, it will spare you having to learn even more about routing and firewalls.

Comment: Could you tell me more about the possible issues of having a double NAT setup?

Comment: re: Double NAT: not a problem for 99% of general web use.  If you have clients expecting to use uPNP, expect that to fail over double NAT.  Security minded folks disable uPNP anyway, so perhaps not a problem.  Only other issue is with inbound services: if you were hosting a service to the rest of the Internet, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents to the preceding post. If you want this to be a wired network, there are some cheap managed switches with a feature called MTU VLAN (Multi-Tenant Unit VLAN), which would probably solve your problems. The TP-Link TL-SG105E/TL-SG108E/TL-SG116E for instance.

Each client port is a single isolated VLAN, single broadcast domain and the uplink port on the swtich gathers them all and forwards (to the router in your case). So you don't need 802.1q capable devices and multi subinterfaces trunk on the router, and still you can have a separate broadcast domain on each port of the switch.